# How do I fill a hole in my basement slab left from furnace removal?

Tags: concrete

We recently had an old oil furnace removed from our garage/laundry room area.  We are now left with a 24"L X 31"W X 17"D hole in the concrete floor. The surrounding walls/floor are concrete.

I have contacted several "concrete contractors" but no one seems to want to tackle this project. So now it is up to us to fix.

Help!

Comment: Pictures would help, along with a description of what you want to do with that space?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what it was about the duplicate (that you posted an "answer" on) that doesn't answer your question. If you need additional info, please ask specifically for that, otherwise, this just seems to be a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 3):

Sand to about 4" of remaining depth, then bagged concrete mix prepared according to the label.

Fill, jiggle, screed, trowel.

Fill the hole with prepared mix to just above level. Jiggle it with a stick or whatever to settle out bubbles and bring a bit of moisture to the surface. Screed across from opposing sides of the original slab in a sawing motion to scrape excess concrete off the patch. Let that rest until the gloss goes away, then trowel smooth with a steel trowel.

Wipe off the original slab with a damp cloth and discard any leftover concrete in your neighbor's flower bed. If confronted, deny everything with a poker face.

Answer (score 2):

> I have contacted several "concrete contractors" but no one seems to want to tackle this project.

That's because it is too small. Given today's economy no one can justify such a small job; they would lose money on it or risk looking really bad if they get called out for overcharging you.

For what sounds like 2-3 60 lb. bags of concrete mix at less than $20 total fixes. Plus or minus a couple bags depending on how deep you want to fill the hole with versus using sand and/or aggregate.  Without pics or more detail, it sounds like a simple indoor aesthetic non structural fix, so a few inches of concrete is all that's needed.  Or fill the whole 17" with crete if you're John Wick and you need to hide your stash.

Watch YouTube on how to do basic do-it-yourself concrete mixing & pouring.

Comment: If the OP really doesn't want to do the work, a job this small would be something you could hire a handyman to do.  Unlike Big Concrete Company, a few hours of work for one person is within their normal scope of work.